# Determine if these are equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, solution-verification

I would appreciate if someone could go through the task and the answers I've got and check if I've done it correct, if not please correct me.

Here is the task:

> Below we have listed some relationships over The set of $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$. For each of these determine whether it is an equivalence relation, and in that case find $[a]$, which is equivalence class to $a$.
>
> 1. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b \rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle\}$
> 2. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle, \langle e,e\rangle, \langle a,b\rangle, \langle b,a\rangle\}$
> 3. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle, \langle e,e\rangle, \langle b,c\rangle, \langle b,d\rangle, \langle c,b\rangle, \langle d,b\rangle\}$
> 4. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle, \langle e,e\rangle, \langle a,c\rangle, \langle b,c\rangle\}$
> 5. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle, \langle e,e\rangle, \langle b,d\rangle, \langle d,b\rangle\}$
> 6. $\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle, \langle c,c\rangle, \langle d,d\rangle, \langle e,e\rangle, \langle b,d\rangle, \langle d,b\rangle, \langle a,c\rangle, \langle c,a\rangle\}$

Here are my answers:

> 1. $[a] = \{a\}$
> 2. $[a]=\{a, b\}$
> 3. $[a]=\{a\}$
> 4. $[a]=\{a, c\}$
> 5. $[a]=\{a\}$
> 6. $[a]=\{a, c\}$
>
> If I'm correct $(1)$, $(3)$, $(5)$ and $(4)$ and $(6)$ are equivalence relations.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: (3) Is not an equivalence relation, because $<c,b>, <b,d> \in R$, but $<c,d> \notin R$ (and hence $R$ is not transitive). Now have a look at the others and try to check the axioms for each of them - carefully.

Comment: thanks, so the rest would be correct then?

Comment: No. Not all of them are equivalence relations. Have a look at them again, and try to mimic what @NoySoffer and I have done.

Comment: Please note my edits to your question, and try to keep your source code more readable in the future -- thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation $R$ is an equivalence relation if and only if it is reflexive AND symmetric AND transitive.

Equivalence classes are determined by an equivalence relation. It makes no sense to speak of equivalence classes when a relation is not an equivalence relation.

Equivalence relation does not mean an "equivalent relation". It is a property of a relation, and not a property between different relations.

---

Relation $(1)$ is not reflexive, hence not an equivalence relation. It is lacking the pair $(e, e)$.

Relation $(2)$ is an equivalence relation. Now you need to find the equivalence *class* of $a$: all the elements that are related to $a$.

Relation $(3)$ is reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive. $(c, b),$ and $(b, d) \in R$, but $(c, d) \notin R$. Since it is not transitive, $R$ cannot be an equivalence relation.

Relation $(4)$ is reflexive and transitive, but not summetric: $(a, c) \in R$, but $(c, a) \notin R$.

Relation $(5)$ is an equivalence relation: it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Now you need to find the equivalence class of $a$: [a]. This is the set of all elements in the set which are related to $a$.

Relation $(6)$ is also an equivalence relation: it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Now you need to find the equivalence class of $a$: $[a]$. This is the set of all elements which are related to $a$.

Comment: The question asks you to find, for those relations that are equivalence relations, what the equivalence class of $3$ is. Equivalence classes do not exist for relations that are not equivalence relations.

Comment: @Dabbish Your equivalence classes $[a]$ for the equivalence relations given by $(2), (5), (6)$ are all CORRECT.

Comment: $(2)$:
$[a]$ $=$ $\{$$a, b$$\}$
$[b]$ $=$ $\{$$b, a$$\}$
$[c]$ $=$ $\{$$c$$\}$
$[d]$ $=$ $\{$$d$$\}$
$[e]$ $=$ $\{$$e$$\}$

So $[a]$ and $[b]$ are equivalence classes?

Comment: Each of $[a], [b], [c], [d], [e]$ (which you've just listed correctly) are equivalence classes of the relation $(2)$. For every equivalence relation, each element belongs to an equivalence class. So while each of the classes you list are equivalence classes, we also have that $[a] = [b]$.

Comment: @amWhy: Could use another UV +1

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if 3 is an equivalence relation, then since $<b,d>$ is in the relation, so should $<d,b>$, but it's not there, and therefore, this isn't an equivalence relation.

Comment: thanks, so the rest would be correct then?

Comment: My bad $f$ is not supposed to be there. I edited the post now

Comment: But $(d, b) \in R$ in relation $3$! You're right that $(3)$ isn't an equivalence relation, but you're wrong about the reason: it IS symmetric. But it ISN'T transitive.

Comment: Sorry, 4 isn't an equivalence relation, because it isn't symmetric

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like *none* of these are equivalence relations.  According to the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), an equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  Relationship (3) fails to be transitive; (4) is neither transitive nor symmetric.  But they *all* fail to be reflexive, because the element $f$ is nowhere in sight.

**Added later**: The answer above was to the original version of the question, which included an element $f$.  In the edited version, only (1) fails to be reflexive.  The equivalence classes for $a$ in the others are as the OP gave them.

Comment: Sorry my bad! $f$ is not supposed to be there. I edited the post now.